# Split strings in php and combine them again without last element (explode)

Tags: php, arrays, regex, string, text

I want to remove the part from this text. `ACCES_ALL_AREAS_1`. Now the text is like this and I want to make it like `ACCES_ALL_AREAS`. I used PHP explode with for loops. That didn't work. And also the word count is not static. Not always 3 as above example.

- `A_PLACE_IN_THE_ABC_3`    ->   `A_PLACE_IN_THE_ABC`
- `ACCES_ALL_AREAS_1`       ->   `ACCES_ALL_AREAS`

Comment: Will there always be a number after the last underscore?

Comment: @ObjectManipulator , yeah sure..Always there's a number at the end

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would probably do this:

```
$string = preg_replace('/_\d+$/', '', $string);
```

- Replace `_` and digits at end `$` of string

For fun you could also do this:

```
$string = rtrim($string, '_1234567890');
```

Or with a range:

```
$string = rtrim($string, '_0..9');
```

Another way:

```
$parts  = explode('_', $string);
array_pop($parts);
$string = implode('_', $parts);
```

- explode on `_` to an array
- pop the last element off of the array
- implode array on `_` back into a string

Comment: Just to show [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/vM5uR7/1) with your expression.

Comment: I like the last example. You can also get the last element value by changing the code like so ```$last = array_pop($parts);```.

Answer (score 1):

Let's see if you have a number of not, it will remove the last array whatsoever it is, give it a try:

```
<?php
$string = "A_PLACE_IN_THE_ABC_3";
$ex = explode('_', $string); // break array
$c = count($ex); // total array
$rm = $c - 1; // 1 place to 0
unset ($ex[$rm]); // Remove unwanted array
$new = join('_', $ex); // regenerate string
echo "New String: ". $new;
```

Another option is substr:

```
$string = "A_PLACE_IN_THE_ABC_3";
echo substr($string, 0, -2); // remove last 2 strings
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
$mystring = "A_PLACE_IN_THE_ABC_3";
$pos = strrpos($mystring, "_");
$result = substr($mystring,0, $pos);   //  A_PLACE_IN_THE_ABC
```